# Customization of the Survey App to create a poll webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I need to display the Poll question on the home page. I used the normal Survey webpart to do it. but it displays the survey description on the page with a "Respond to the Survey" link. Once I click on that link, it redirects me to a page that contains the questions and the options. I need to display similar page on the home page containing question and options on the home page.Is there any way to display the question and the options of the poll ?

Any Help Would be thankful

Answer (score 1):

(I'll assume you can't develop or deploy custom server side code, or don't want to pay for third-party poll web parts with this answer).

I would abandon trying to force-fit the out of the box Survey part into a poll.

I have seen good javascript samples out there that give poll functionality. (search google for SharePoint javascript poll).

This will allow you to put the javascript on a page (e.g. via a content editor web part) and will be more of a solution tailored to what you are trying to achieve.